# Sticky sidebar doesn't have the correct top space in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble with firefox to show the entire sidebar. As you can see from the imagem it seams to not space itself properly from the top, hidding the first item!

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfDQv.png)

Here is the CSS:

```
/*
* Sidebar
*/

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.sidebar-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 48px; /* Height of navbar */
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
  padding-top: .5rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}

.sidebar .nav-link .feather {
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #999;
}

.sidebar .nav-link.active {
  color: #007bff;
}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover .feather,
.sidebar .nav-link.active .feather {
  color: inherit;
}

.sidebar-heading {
  font-size: .75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This is part of one of the bootstrap templates!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because it's inside a grid and using responsive classes so when you make your window smaller or bigger, the 'spacing' changes.

```html
<div class="row">
    <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-sticky">...</div>
    </nav>
    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
        ...
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that on chrome everything is working fine but on firefoz is not. Doesn't matter the size of the window...
Thank you.